how to make the longitude and latitude lines on map disappear in google maps api
I have this map in js code in google map api, and I cannot find solution how to make longitude and latitude lines on map disappear.
An image showing the longitude and latitude lines I want to remove
My attempt so far:
guessMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("guessMap"), {
    center: { lat: 0, lng: 0 },
    zoom: 2,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    fullscreenControl: false,
    minZoom: 2, // Minimalny zoom
    maxZoom: 15, // Maksymalny zoom
    restriction: { // Ograniczenia geograficzne
      latLngBounds: {
        north: 85,
        south: -85,
        east: 180,
        west: -180,
      },
      strictBounds: true,
    },
    styles: [ // Styl mapy
      {
        "featureType": "administrative",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{ "visibility": "on" }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "landscape",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{ "visibility": "on" }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "elementType": "labels",
        "stylers": [{ "visibility": "on" }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "road",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{ "visibility": "on" }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "transit",
        "elementType": "labels",
        "stylers": [{ "visibility": "on" }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{ "visibility": "on" }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{ "visibility": "off" }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "administrative.locality",
        "elementType": "labels",
        "stylers": [{ "visibility": "on" }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "administrative.neighborhood",
        "elementType": "labels",
        "stylers": [{ "visibility": "on" }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "administrative.province",
        "elementType": "labels",
        "stylers": [{ "visibility": "on" }]
      }
    ]
});

I tried to enable and disable some things but when I turn off administrative geometry borders in countries disappear too.

Why is this tagged for both version 2 and 3? Those are not latitude and longitude lines, they're the date line and the equator.

Proof of concept fiddle (based on duplicate): fiddle
